# ajuda com expressão regular php

Tags: php, html

Preciso remover todas as tags junto com o conteudo e o fechamento da tag, quando for script a tag.
Exemplo
$variavel="Alguma coisaAlguma coisa2alguma funcao javascript";

Quero remover isso tudo do html

```
<script>alguma funcao javascript</script>
```

A ideia é tipo assim

```
$variavel = preg_replace('<script*>*</script>', '', $variavel);
```

Mas nao funcionou.
Explicando o regex como deve ficar:
Ele vai dar replace quando começar com

Comment: Use a função strip_tags.

Comment: strip tags nao me serve, pois so quero remover as tags script, as outras não, e não quero remover somente a tag não, no caso da script quero remover é tudo tag, conteudo tudo junto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fazer parse de HTML com regex é desaconselhado. No caso do exemplo é +/- simples e algo como  `/<script[^>]*>[^<]*<\/script>/` [(link)](https://regex101.com/r/Gv9mRg/1)  poderia funcionar.

Solução melhor seria usar o [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php) que é feito para isso e recebe como segundo argumento as tags permitidas.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```
$html = "
<p>algo</p>
<script>alguma funcao javascript</script>
<div>algo</div>
";

$html_limpo = strip_tags($html, '<p><div>');
echo $html_limpo;
```

O resultado seria:

```
<p>algo</p>
alguma funcao javascript
<div>algo</div>
```

Comment: Tá mas preciso liberar todas as tags, menos a script

Comment: @MegaAnim dei 2 exemplos, um com regex que faz o que queres: retira o script e o conteudo; e outro onde tens de indicar as tags "seguras".

Comment: @MegaAnim https://ideone.com/uzwO8P

Comment: Obrigada, deu certo xD

Comment: @MegaAnim ótimo. Se quiseres podes clicar e marcar a resposta como aceite.

Comment: Deve utilizar o `/i`, porque se não o `ScRiPt` iria passar, mas de qualquer maneira se isto for para prevenir XSS é inútil.

Comment: Ops, parece que algo deu errado.... <script type="text/javascript"> passou

Comment: @MegaAnim https://ideone.com/dE6F2F Depende como estás a escapar esse conteúdo, para mim funciona. Podes mostrar o script todo que queres remover e o que pretendes corrigir com isso?

Comment: Bom eu ja fiz a maior bagunça aqui testando varias funções rsrs..
Consegui com essa $str = preg_replace('/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script[^>]*>/', '', $str);

Comment: Sergio, para entender melhor o que estou fazendo, é um tradutor de páginas, preciso remover as tags e o conteudo das tags script, para diminuir o tamanho do codigo da pagina, já que vou substituir o conteudo dentro de um iframe, os scripts nesse caso ja foram carregados, então removê-los não vai afetar o funcionamento dela.
Mas acho que não vou conseguir fazer meu projeto, pois tem outras complicações, remover o script, style, e noscript não foi suficiente pra diminuir o tamanho da pagina suficiente, pois ainda preciso ler os caracteres da pagina um por um pra detectar onde estão as tags

Comment: @MegaAnim em relação à pergunta e à duvida acho que podes marcar uma das respostas como aceite, mesmo que no final no teu caso tenhas resolvido de outra maneira, pois ambas as respostas tentam resolver o que perguntas-te. Em relação ao teu problema é dificil ajudar mais sem saber todo o código que está na página.

Comment: ainda nao sei marcar melhor resposta... nunca achei essa opcao aqui

Comment: @MegaAnim https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/129

Answer (score 0):

> /!\ Não recomendo utilizar isso!

Você pode utilizar o REGEX:

```
/<script.*?>(.*?<\/script.*?>)?/i
```

Portanto:

```
<ScrIpT>alert()</ScrIpT>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">alguma funcao javascript</script>
<Script src="site.com">
```

Serão removidos.

---

Agora depende do seu objetivo com este REGEX. Se for para proteger de XSS esqueça,  ainda estaria sendo possível:

```
<img onerror="alert('XSS')">
<svg/onload=alert('XSS')>
```

[Isso é somente dois dos milhares de outros exemplos.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: não é pra xss não...
Estou construindo um tradutor, e preciso remover as tags script pois elas nao deverão  ter o conteudo convertido, quero converter só o texto visivel na tela., entao primeiro removo script, e style, depois transformo o resto em um array com todos os textos separados, converto texto por texto e depois substituo diretamente dentro do iframe do site que desejo converter